# How can I get the value of iskeyword as characters?

Tags: neovim

I am trying to get the value of `iskeyword` as character. When I run `set iskeyword?`, I get `iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255`. Using `48-57` as an example, how can I turn them back to characters? Is there any helper function in vim or lua that can help me do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`nr2char()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#nr2char()) function:

```
echo nr2char(48)
```

This will display the character for the number zero, '0'.

To print that first range using Vimscript you could, for example, do something like:

```
for i in range(48, 57)
   echo nr2char(i)
endfor
```

That will print out characters representing numbers 0-9, one per line.

Alternatively, to put the associated characters in a list:

```
let chlist = map(range(48, 57), {_, val -> nr2char(val)})
```

Another function that does the same number-to-char conversions but can handle multiple numbers at once is [`list2str()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#list2str())

```
echo list2str(range(48, 57))
```

...or the equivalent "method call"...

```
echo range(48, 57)->list2str()
```

Both will display the string `0123456789`.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve a string containing all (ASCII + 127-255) iskeyword characters via the following:

```
echo substitute(join(map(range(256), 'nr2char(v:val)'), ''), '[^[:keyword:]]', '', 'g')
```

In patterns `\k` refers to characters in `iskeyword` (it is dynamic with this option), however this cannot be easily negated.  Instead we can use the class expression `[:keyword:]` which can easily be negated in a character class via `[^[:keyword:]]`.  We create a length 255 string containing all of the characters of interest, and substitute out all non-keyword chars.